# iOS: Detect if the app was installed from an ad or organic install

Tags: ios, swift, ads, appdelegate, google-ads-script

I have a process that should be done if the app is downloaded via an ad and not an organic download. Is Their a way to detect if the app was downloaded via an ad? That means the user pressed on a link which redirected the user to the App Store and then download the app. I need the link that redirected the user to the store.

I tried to add some logs in the 3 functions:

- `application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`
- `application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`
- `application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([UIUserActivityRestoring]?) -> Void) -> Bool`

How I'm testing? I am pressing a link that redirects me to my app in the store, then run the app from Xcode. I'm expecting (in the first open of the app) to receive the url that redirected me in one of these functions. However, the first function is returning `nil` for `launchOptions` and the app is not entering the last 2 functions.

I'm I missing something?

Comment: "Starting with iOS 14.5, apps on the App Store need to receive the user’s permission through the AppTrackingTransparency framework before collecting data used to track them. This requirement protects the privacy of App Store users." We were using an add tracking sdk to track our ad campaigns on iOS and stopped using it as of 14.5 I think its some very high number like 90% of users decline add tracking (as they should) so tracking on iOS seems almost obsolete now

Comment: Leting aside the need to request permissions for tracking Users/devices, the only currently viable way to achieve what you are asking is for the link to redirect to a page you control, that page will add a piece of information in the pasteboard and then redirect the user to download the app. When the app is launched it will check the pasteboard for that information. This is a best effort approach as there is no native way provided.

Comment: Did you have got a solution?

Comment: So, since iOS 14.5 there is no way to check if an user installed the app though our own App Store ads? It's incredible that Apple offer ads without the most important analytic, conversion ;/